# remove shapes from canvas using fabricjs

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs, html2canvas

I need to remove a shape from the canvas. I'm using the below code but some times it doesn't work, i'm using fabricjs for creating shapes. can anyone help me

```
canvas2.remove(rect);
rect.remove();
canvas2.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what situation that code you have would not work. the below code works every time for me. If you can post a code snippet that fails then it will be easier to help you.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false, preserveObjectStacking:true });

var rect = new fabric.Rect({ 
  left: 100, 
  top: 100, 
  width: 50, 
  height: 50, 
})

canvas.add(rect);

setTimeout(function() {
 canvas.remove(rect);
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```